# SPA with React Router v6 - How to avoid downloading images from public folder?-Netlify

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, netlify

I want to build a single page application with react.js and react router v6.
I have images in the public folder that i use inside my application.
The problem is that when i open the developer tools, and network, i see the photos downloading when i go to specific pages that uses those photos. Imagine a profile image.
The project is deployed on netlify .
So the project is single page indeed, because i empty the logs, click on the page . Nothing downloads excepts the images used.
Can i somehow put the images elsewhere so they dont need to be downloaded?

Comment: This question is not clear as the images used in the page expected to be downloaded from where ever it is sourced. May be you are trying to achieve something else?

Comment: The images are in the public folder in the react application . i uploaded the whole project on github . from there i want to netlify , and deployed my project live . but when i try to view projects page , it goes and dowload the images . i tought that because i put the images in public folder, they are already there to be served.